# Unpairing a PR2 from a basestation

Tags: pr2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How do you unpair a PR2 from a basestation?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9329/unpairing-a-pr2-from-a-basestation/) by [edgan](https://answers.ros.org/users/258/edgan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 66 on 2011-03-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Edit /etc/robot-foward.conf on the base station, and remove the corresponding lines for the robot you want to unpair. Then run "sudo robot-forward start".

---

Originally posted by [edgan](https://answers.ros.org/users/258/edgan/) with karma: 66 on 2011-03-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0